# Want to show svg in an iframe and show a scrollbar to let users to pan the image in chrome/ie8

Tags: html, xhtml, iframe, svg, google-chrome

html:

```
 <iframe scrolling="yes" src="svgfile.svg"></iframe>
```

svgfile.svg:

```
 <svg width="2636pt" height="2478pt" viewBox="-1 -1 2635 2477" xmlns="...">
     <g id="node1" class="node">....</g>
     ...
 </svg>
```

This won't show the scrollbar in chrome/ie8...
This was OK in FF...

Other solution not using iframe can be acceptable.
Or just rescaling the whole svg image(bigger than the original page) to fit to the original page might be ok as well.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support scrolling of SVG images yet.  (Try opening just the image and you'll see.)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the Iframe attribute is `scrolling="yes"` or "auto" not `scrollbar`.

Comment: unfortunately scrolling="yes" didnt work as well. updating the question.

Comment: try setting the width and height of the iframe.